# Barycentre of two planets and calculating velocity shift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, astronomy, celestial-mechanics

I find my self puzzled by this question, and I cant see anything wrong with my derivation, which leads me to believe that there is something I am missing within how the velocity shift is calculated. I am wondering if anyone could maybe expanded on what I have done and my be missing. 
[image]

My full derivation for the question, unfortunate I can upload my diagram, so I will just show the maths.

So I start with a simply two body problem and impose the two conditions

$$M_1r_1=M_2r_2$$
and 
$$R=r_1+r_2$$
using these two conditions I rearrange my first equation to make $r_1$ the subject and sub into my second equation to form.

$$R=\frac{M_2r_2}{M_1}+r_2$$

Now rearranging this equation to make $r_2$ the subject I get the following

$$r_2=R\left(\frac{M_2+M_1}{M_1}\right)$$

So now using Newton's law of gravitational force and centripetal force and writing centripetal force in term of angular velocity, I can form the following equation,

$$\frac{GM_1M_2}{R^2}=M_2r_2\omega $$

substituting in my value for $r_2$, I can derive the following:

$$\frac{GM_1M_2}{R^2}=\left(\frac{M_2M_1}{M_1+M_2}\right)R\left(\frac{2\pi }{P}\right)^{^2},\:\omega =\frac{2\pi }{T}$$

Now with some rearranging I derive Kepler's third law as shown below:
$$\frac{P^2}{R^3}=\frac{4\pi ^2}{G\left(M_1+M_2\right)}$$

As stated, assuming a circular orbit, can use the following relation

$$Pv_1=2\pi r_1\:,\:Pv_2=2\pi \:r_2\:$$

Rearranging these two equations and substituting into my second equation for $R$ I get the following result:

$$R=r_1+r_2=\frac{Pv_1}{2\pi }+\frac{Pv_2}{2\pi \:}\:,\:\therefore R=\frac{P}{2\pi }\left(v_1+v_2\right)$$

So now substituting this into Kepler's third law, and simplifying, I obtain:

$$M_1+M_2=\frac{P\left(v_1+v_2\right)}{2\pi G}$$

So now using the fact that

$$v_1M_1=v_2M_2\:,\:v_2=\frac{M_1}{M_2}v_1$$

and subsituing the result obtained for $v_2$ into my equation for $M_1+M_2$ I get the following version, once again simplified

$$\frac{M_2^3}{\left(M_1+M_2\right)^2}=\frac{Pv_1^3}{2\pi G},$$

so with a bit of rearranging to make $v^3$ the subject, I make it to be:

$$v^3=\frac{\left(2\pi G\right)\left(M_2\right)^3}{P\left(M_1+M_2\right)},\:where\:M_2=jupiter\:\&\:M_1=White\:Dwarf$$

Now here my problem when I plug in the numbers and I get around $18.6m/s$ which is half of what the value should be. Now I can't really see an issue with what I have derived ( biased ), but if it not the derivation then there something I miss within the measuring technique. I have looked at various of graphs yet find no reason to why my value is half. Have I made an error in the derivation or is this more of a theory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are correct (for an edge-on orbit). However, *your* $v$ is the radial velocity amplitude, not the peak-to-peak amplitude... that is, the observed radial velocity varies from $-v$ to $+v$.

Comment: so would the mean that I need to derive the equation with sin(i) and say from 90 to 270, I am sort of new to this, or could I simply multiply through by 2?

Comment: Would I have to make a subsituiton of the type $v_{obvs}=v/sin(i)$

Comment: The peak-to-peak amplitude is $2v$.

Comment: Ah! I have just been reading, thank you very much for the guidance much appreciated.